# How to move a UIImageView with Touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimageview, user-interaction

I'm trying to create moving functionality to my imageView (maskPreview in the code below), so that users can move a picture, which is contained in maskPreview, around the screen. Here's my code for touch begin and touch moved:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if ([touches count]==1) {
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    originalOrigin = [touch locationInView:maskPreview];
}
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if ([touches count]==1) {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint lastTouch = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat movedDistanceX = originalOrigin.x-lastTouch.x;
    CGFloat movedDistanceY = originalOrigin.y-lastTouch.y;
    [maskPreview setFrame:CGRectMake(maskPreview.frame.origin.x+movedDistanceX, maskPreview.frame.origin.y + movedDistanceY, maskPreview.frame.size.width, maskPreview.frame.size.height)];
}
}
```

but I'm getting some weird responses from the app. I haven't put restrictions on how far the imageview can move, i.e. to prevent it from going out of the screen, but even if it's a small move, my imageview goes wild and disappears.

Thanks alot in advance for all the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implementing `touchesBegan` and so on is way overkill in this modern world. You're just confusing the heck out of yourself, and your code will quickly become impossible to understand or maintain. Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer; that's what it's for. Making a view draggable with a UIPanGestureRecognizer is trivial. Here's the action handler for a UIPanGestureRecognizer that makes the view draggable:

```
- (void) dragging: (UIPanGestureRecognizer*) p {
    UIView* vv = p.view;
    if (p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint delta = [p translationInView: vv.superview];
        CGPoint c = vv.center;
        c.x += delta.x; c.y += delta.y;
        vv.center = c;
        [p setTranslation: CGPointZero inView: vv.superview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Matt, you are an absolute genius!! Would've rated your answer but I don't have enough reputation!! made my life so much easier!!

Comment: Just FYI, that code came straight out of my book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023562.do - Lots more where that came from...

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code.  First, this line is wrong:

```
CGPoint lastTouch = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
```

It should be this:

```
CGPoint lastTouch = [touch previousLocationInView:maskPreview];
```

Really, you shouldn't even be using `previousLocationInView:`.  You should just be using `locationInView:` like this:

```
CGPoint lastTouch = [touch locationInView:maskPreview];
```

Second, you are getting the signs of `movedDistanceX` and `movedDistanceY` wrong.  Change them to this:

```
CGFloat movedDistanceX = lastTouch.x - originalOrigin.x;
CGFloat movedDistanceY = lastTouch.y - originalOrigin.y;
```

Also, the documentation for `touchesBegan:withEvent:` says this:

> If you override this method without calling `super` (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, if only as stub (empy) implementations.

So make sure you're also overriding `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`.

Anyway, you can do this quite a bit more simply.  One way is to make `touchesBegan:withEvent:` empty and do all the work in `touchesMoved:withEvent:` by using both `previousLocationInView:` and `locationInView:`, and updating `maskPreview.center` instead of `maskPreview.frame`.  You won't even need the `originalOrigin` instance variable:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches count]==1) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint p0 = [touch previousLocationInView:maskPreview];
        CGPoint p1 = [touch locationInView:maskPreview];
        CGPoint center = maskPreview.center;
        center.x += p1.x - p0.x;
        center.y += p1.y - p0.y;
        maskPreview.center = center;
    }
}
```

Another way to do this is by using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for the answer, and realised the mistakes in my code!! I used Matt's tutorial for UIPanGestureRecognizer, and it worked a treat. But the bit about over-riding all touch events was a great help, I didn't know and didn't think we should do that.